# How to uniquely identify a row in a table where there are no unique columns in Ingres DB?

Tags: uniqueidentifier, ingres

I am trying to find a way to uniquely identify a row in a table where there aren't any unique columns. I have seen that it is advised not to use tid as a unique row identifier so I was wondering what are the other possible ways?

I have tried to create a new column and populate it with an incrementing value in the following manner:

-- Create a column

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] 
ADD COLUMN [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT;
```

-- Reconstruct

```
MODIFY [TABLENAME] TO RECONSTRUCT;
```

-- Create

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [SEQUENCENAME]
```

-- Update the newly made column with sequence

```
UPDATE [TABLENAME]                                             
SET [ID] = [SEQUENCENAME].nextval;
```

Comment: May be a unique _combination_ of columns?

Comment: @mustaccio. Thank you for the suggestion, but we have no way of knowing what those column combinations might be dynamically.